# Pydantic serialization of containers of mixed types

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-v2

Can Pydantic v2 handle containers of mixed types? For example, how would serialization take place in a class defined as follows:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
  foo_list: list
```

If the code above is not the recommended way of doing things, what is the recommended way of defining lists that may contain elements of different types?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `typing.Union` along with `typing.List`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, List

class Foo(BaseModel):
    foo_list: List[Union[int, str, float, dict, list]]
```

Comment: `List` has been deprecated for years; just use `list`.

Comment: The following code is from [.pydantic.dev] (https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/types/list_types/)

```
from typing import Deque, List, Optional, Tuple
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Model(BaseModel):
    simple_list: Optional[list] = None
    list_of_ints: Optional[List[int]] = None

    simple_tuple: Optional[tuple] = None
    tuple_of_different_types: Optional[Tuple[int, float, bool]] = None
    deque: Optional[Deque[int]] = None
```
I guess you may use both, ```List``` or ```list```, maybe?

Comment: No, it means pydantic's documentation is out of date. The documentation for [`typing.List` itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) says it is deprecated. (Prior to Python 3.9, you couldn't use, e.g., `list[int]`, so `typing` defined `List` to be used in its place. As of Python 3.9, you *can* write `list[int]`, so there is no longer any need for `List`. Same is true for `Dict` and `Tuple`.

Comment: Back to the original question: Union works if there are no nested structures, but passing a list of lists or a list of dicts still fails to serialize properly.